# Input field name starts with a number

Tags: html, xhtml

I have an input field whose name is an MD5 string e.g.:

`<input type="hidden" name="7815696ecbf1c96e6894b779456d330e" value="1">`

Now I understand that having a number as the first letter in an input field name is generally bad practice, but are there any side-effects to this such as a certain browser won't send it in the POST request?

Comment: You should also be aware on how your server side framework (if using one) handles inputs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An ID attribute would have had to begin with a letter [as per the HTML 4.01 W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name), however since the NAME attribute of input elements is of CDATA type ([Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4)), this restriction does not apply.

One real restriction you get on NAME attributes is when you submit a form with the GET method, because in this case, form data must be restricted to ASCII codes ([Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3)).

Comment: The name attribute is of type CDATA and is not a SGML name token as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Willis: You're right... I fixed my answer to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 8):

The HTML spec doesn't restrict the control name in any way.  In fact it even says that the control name is URL-encoded and that spaces and non-alphanumeric characters are handled in a certain way, so obviously the designers anticipated names having an arbitrary format.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, you should have no problem in any browser.
But you can always consider to prepend some kind of string, also for convenience:

**e.g.,**

```
<input type="hidden" name="h.7815696ecbf1c96e6894b779456d330e" value="1">
```

<sup>Which can help someway.</sup>