# How to get the text part of this DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have in my 
    `this.nameHtml`
a DOM object with value:

```
<span class='test-name'>333</span>
```

I want to access the innerHTML i.e. `333`

basically I am creating a checkbox element and want to assign the 333 value from DOM object in name attribute as follow:

```
checkBox = document.createElement("input");
checkBox.type = "checkbox";
checkBox.name = this.nameHtml;   // Here i want to store 333 
checkBox.className = "TriageCheckBox";
```

Please suggest a way.

Comment: What are you trying? A checkbox can only hold the value checked or unchecked. It is not meant to store strings or numbers.

Comment: Sorry Benedikt, I meant, checkBox.name

Comment: Keep in mind that you may run in trouble, when the name field begins with a number. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469355/input-field-name-starts-with-a-number

Answer (score 1):

Try using `innerHTML` property :

```
checkBox.name = document.getElementByClassName("test-name")[0].innerHTML;
```

**NB** : `document.getElementByClassName("test-name")[0]` get first element with `test-name` class, be sure to adjust index if multiple ones.

Comment: Hi Hotted24, unfortunately I can't use your suggestion, there will be dynamically generated checkboxes hence keeping track of index number will be difficult

Comment: Then give them IDs and use getElementById("") ;) I believe you can use a simple global var like an index to make it unique =) BTW, instead of document.getEle, if you have access to the object from the inside, it's simpler : checkBox.name = this.innerHTML;

Comment: Thanks Hotted24. Yes, did in your way !

Answer (score 0):

```
checkBox.name = this.nameHtml.innerText;
```

Beware of innerHtml! This may print unwanted html code and destroy your site structure!
[Difference between innerText and innerHTML in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript)

Regards,
Benedikt